# Install 2 different apks in one installation

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Is there any way I can release one apk file which will install two different apks ?

I have 2 different apks and I want that when the customer installs one installation from Google play then 2 apks will be installed.

Any idea ?

Comment: What is the purpose of the two separate APKs?

Comment: These are 2 separated applications which were developed for 2 different needs for a customer and when installing one of them it is very reasonable to install the second so we want to install them both in same download&install procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Install the first APK and then launch an Intent to install the second.
Use

```
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

as data.

There's no way of installing apps without user's consent so Play will be opened and the user can accept and proceed.

Comment: Thanks. Does the customer should click on something for the second apk to install or all the second installation process happens behind the hood ?